# How to render only field label

Tags: entities

Is it possible to render only the field label from $view->result , 
like render the field value only

```
$display['label']='hidden';
```

print render(field_view_field('node',$node,'field_date',$display));

Answer (score 0):

found it here
 $view->field['field_description']->options['label'];